# No module named 'flask_restful' according to command prompt

Tags: python, command-line-interface, flask-restful

I am trying to learn the basics of apis and flask restful, and was trying to run the minimal api in the flask documentation.

I installed flask and flask-restful into the scripts folder in the virtual environment using command prompt, and my ide picked up that these modules are installed.

However, having saved the script, when I try to run the python file in command prompt as an http server, it comes back with the following error:-
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_restful'

As far as I can tell, the module is definitely actually there (since py-charm makes it pretty clear if a module referred to in the code is not actually installed).

So two questions - what is going on? And more importantly, how do I fix it?

(PS - the above is with respect to windows command prompt)

---

My code for reference

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello':'world'}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld,'/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `flask-restful` installed on your system? If not just use pip for installation, and type in your command prompt this command: `pip install flask-restful`